# AJAX SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to find out the issue with this for days. As my data is being sent and retrieved, yet it doesn't post into my div.. Why? I did a test and found that I a SyntaxERROR unexpected character.. And can I find it.. Can I heck.

Can someone look through this and tell me of any mistakes please.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#mycommentform").submit(function() {

        var streamidcontent = $(this).children("#streamidcontent").val();
        var contents = $(this).children("#contents").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_add.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { streamidcontent: streamidcontent, contents: contents }, 
            success: function(data){  
                $("#containerid").html('<div class="stream_comment_holder" id="comment_holder_'+data['comment_streamitem']+'">\
                <div id="comment_list_'+data['comment_streamitem']+'">\
                <div id="tgy"></div><div class="stream_comment" id="comment_'+data['comment_id']+'" style="margin-top:0px;">\
                <table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px></a><td valign=top align=left>\
                <a href="/profile.php?username='+data['username']+'">'+data['first']+'</a>\
                <div class="commentholder">'+data['first']+'</div><br/>\
                <div id="commentactivitycontainer"></div></div></table></div></div>\
                <div class="form"><form id="mycommentform" method="POST" class="form_statusinput">\
                <input type="hidden"  name="streamidcontent" id="streamidcontent" value="'+data['comment_streamitem']+'">\
                <input type="text" name="contents" id="contents" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">\
                <input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed"></form></div>\
                <div class="stream_comment_holder" style="display:;"><div class="like_name"><b>\
                <a href="profile.php?username='+data['username']+'">You Like This</a>\
                </b></div></div>');
                  alert("SUCCESS!!!");
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
 }
 });
        return false
    });
 });
 </script>
```

REPONSE

```
INSERT INTO streamdata_comments(comment_poster, comment_streamitem, comment_datetime, comment_content) VALUES (10,4090,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'fff'){"comment_id":"2016","comment_streamitem":"4090","username":"hazy","id":"10","first":"Lucy","middle":"","last":"Botham"}
```

PHP PAGE

```
<?php
session_start();
require"include/rawfeeds_load.php";

if(isset($_POST['streamidcontent'])&isset($_POST['contents'])){
rawfeeds_user_core::add_comment($_POST['streamidcontent'],$_POST['contents']);


$json = array();
$check = "SELECT comment_id, comment_datetime, comment_streamitem, comment_poster FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_poster='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND comment_streamitem='".$_POST['streamidcontent']."' ORDER BY comment_datetime DESC";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
$json['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
$json['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];
mysqli_free_result($check1);

$check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
$json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
$json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
$json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
$json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
$json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];
mysqli_free_result($check1);

echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Comment: The syntax error is probably in the JSON response itself, not your JavaScript code. What does the response text look like?

Comment: You may want to consider using a Javascript templating library instead of a massive string.

Comment: Oh yes, that too - not all browsers will allow you to break lines like that. (I think.)

Comment: Where do I find my response text? Forgive me I wouldn't consider myself a pro atm. You talking about in Firbug @pointy

Comment: @dave yes, in Firebug - when it shows you the response, you can click on it to "open" it. It will show the Request headers, Response headers, and the content.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO streamdata_comments(...) VALUES (...)` part should **not** be there. Looks like you `echo`d your SQL statement for testing purposes.

Comment: I've posted it in the question.

Comment: That's what's coming back from the server?  Well that's certainly not JSON.

Comment: You are echoing the sql query before the json breaking the format. Remove that and it should work. The response should just be `{"comment_id":"2016","comment_streamitem":"4090","username":"hazy","id":"10","first":"Lucy","middle":"","last":"Botham"}`

Comment: I don't understand. I built the comments off the main status. And its exactly the same. And the main status inserts fine. What is it I need to do? Could you point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'll add my php page to the question so you know what it looks like. Added the php page to the question.

Comment: Using firebug add a watch expression for data.d and see what you get.

Comment: So how am I to insert the comment and comment id and collect the data together without getting an error and just getting the response back?

Comment: @Thomas you were right. I'd made the mistake of echoing out in the function. And because I knew the function was working I NEVER went back into the page. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thomas stated above. I was echoing the SQL query out into my function. I removed this and its now working perfectly.

Comment: Just 2 more tips: in JS `data['something']` is the same as `data.something` but the latter is more readable. And as @arxanas pointed out you could look at using a JS templating system. I personally use mustache (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: Thank you @Thomas I will take your suggestions on board.