# php header is working but with mistakes

Tags: php, html, ajax, header, smarty

Actually I'm trying to redirect to the index after logging in with ajax button 
but what is happening is strange , header is not taking me to the index.php !
i just get the HTML code of the index.php in my login.php page !! 
I'm using Smarty to separate the  html from php code , and I don't know how to fix the problem !
click the login and get the HTML of the index in login page ! 
why ?

in login.php page

```
 if ($_POST['action'] == 'login') {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
}
```

the ajax function :

```
function ajax3(Div_Submit,Div_Response,SuccessScript,Data_Submit) 
{
    var Type = 1;


     var Aj_type = "POST";
        var post_data = '';
        if(!Data_Submit) 
            post_data = $('#'+Div_Submit+' *').serialize();
        else
            post_data = Data_Submit;
        $.ajax({
            type: Aj_type,
            url: document.URL,
            data: post_data,
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function(xhr)
        {
           $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="images/loading.gif" />',
        css: {  border: 'none',  backgroundColor: 'transparent' } });
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Ajax-Request", "true");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#'+Div_Response).html(response+'<script>'+SuccessScript+'</script>');
        },
        complete: function(){
        $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

the html button call :

```
  <div class="buttons" >
                <a class="positive" onclick="$('#login_action').val('login');ajax3('login_form','login_form','','')">
                    <img src="images/checkbox_checked.png" alt=""/>
                  <font size="3px">  login </font>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can't redirect to another page through AJAX below ajax client side. use javascript to redirect page

Comment: okay I'm trying another way now , thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wouldn't work as what you expected.

It should be something like this.

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'login') {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     echo "success";
}
```

On your javascript/jquery file.
have something like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: "login.php",
 success:function(data){
   if(data == "success") window.location = "index.php";
}
});
```

Comment: when clicking login button now it loads the HTML twice ! one inside another , and it outputs success !

Comment: If you have followed the code above, that wouldn't happend. :)

Comment: I put it as you say but this problem always happening !!
after clicking a button getting the tab or page inside itself ,

Comment: can you help me ? I did what you say but I'm still stacked on the same page :(

Comment: I'm not allowed to post an answer yet so I'll post it here : 
I solved this problem with help of you guys , thank you all :) The answer is :

 success:function(response){
                            $('#'+Div_Response).html(response);
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                    } 

without echoing anything in the php page and without if condition .

Answer (score 4):

With AJAX, this is the expected output. What happens is that the **AJAX request** itself is being redirected to index.php, which I what is then outputted and returned to that request.

If you want to redirect to index.php from AJAX, you would need to exit with a specific code, or a JSON-encoded value and catch that in the AJAX result itself.

Example:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'login') {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      echo json_encode(array('redirect' => 'index.php'));
      exit;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax(
    url: 'your-url',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            document.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: this code outputs 
    {"redirect":"index.php"} and I'm still the in login.php

Comment: yes, that's the JSON output - did you update the JavaScript part to catch the redirect as per my example here?

Comment: yep , I did that .
in the firebug I'm getting the Response value is {"redirect":"index.php"} and the JSON value is   
 
redirect
 

"index.php"
and I'm still in login.php but the html has gone , just the header and the footer remain

Comment: perhaps it would be good idea to update your question with the JavaScript part, as that's where it would seem to raise problems for you

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean by JavaScript part  ?

Comment: you only showed us your PHP part in the question - care to show us your JavaScript as well?

Comment: yeah, that's why it couldn't work - you have dataType set to "text", which will always expect text output and ignore any JSON that might come out of the request

Comment: mmmm , I see , but i can't change this function , I have to modify my ways to suit it , because I'm working with a team

Comment: well, you already accepted Elson's answer, which is a way to go for you in this case - so going with his code should work ;)

Comment: hehe I thought it's just like the "like " in facebook as saying thank you :$ pardon I'm new here !! didn't know that meant !

Comment: I solved this problem with help of you guys , thank you all :) The answer is :

 success:function(response){
                            $('#'+Div_Response).html(response);
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                    } 

without echoing anything in the php page and without if condition .

Answer (score 0):

u can get success response whenever login credentials are appropriate , at that moment change the window location using javascript or jquery..

Comment: use json code and dont forget to parse json, in client side. Zathrus Writer missed that part in code

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data); above if condition at success function

Comment: @Ravi there is no need to parse JSON with jQuery, as jQuery automatically does that for you once it determines that the output is a JSON-formatted string

Comment: @Zathrus yes, but this did not work for ME, I had to use JSON.parse then only it redirected in my example

Comment: @Ravi do you mean like this ? 
success: function(data) {
        if (data.redirect) {
             data = JSON.parse(data);
            document.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
    }
});

Comment: no,
success: function(data) { data = JSON.parse(data); if (data.redirect) {  document.location.href = data.redirect; } } });

Comment: @Ravi what browser and OS did you use please?

Comment: I'm sorry guys but I'm a beginner :$ and I'm lost with all this  JSON and ajax ! I don't know where to look , especially without a debugger , I'm using Cent OS server on a virtual box with Linux platform also

Comment: @RAvi SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Its working fine with me, checkout Safey :                     jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "check_login.php",  
      
    success: function(theResponse){ 
                                             obj = JSON.parse(theResponse);
       
       if(obj.redirect=="testtest"){} });

Comment: ok , I'm trying :(
inside the if condition I put :  document.location.href = data.redirect; 
and in the login.php :
????

Comment: echo json_encode(array('redirect' => 'index.php'));
      exit;

is that correct ?

Comment: now I'm getting {"redirect":"index.php"} echoed and the html of login.html inside the login page , it's like the page sending itself to itself !

Comment: can you use : window.location.href=data.redirect; ??? Instead of document.location.href

Comment: same thing ! 
I'm still getting this error 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

obj = JSON.parse(theResponse);

Comment: Are you echoing something other than json encoded string in php file?? pls check properly

Comment: no , just this ,  echo json_encode(array('redirect' => 'index.php'));

Comment: you've got to refer to this my friend : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143349/ajax-syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character

Comment: I solved this problem with help of you guys , thank you all :) The answer is :

 success:function(response){
                            $('#'+Div_Response).html(response);
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                    } 

without echoing anything in the php page and without if condition .